# how to clear a boost::iterator_range

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, range

I have pointer ***p*** to a `boost::iterator` range pointing to a vector. I cleared the underlying vector. Since the underlying vector is cleared, the iterator pair of the `boost::iterator` range is *invalidated*. There is no *clear* function for a `boost::iterator_range`.

How can I clear the `boost::iterator` range?

> *p->begin() = p->end()*

***does not*** result in `p.empty()` returning ***true***

Answer (score 1):

Using a range `[end(), end())` does in fact make `empty()` return true. However, you can also just assign a default constructed iterator range:

```
*p = {};
```

Here's a live demonstration of various approaches:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a041f0b2e5358013)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> is { 1,2,3 };
    auto range = boost::make_iterator_range(is.begin(), is.end());
    std::cout << "range empty? " << std::boolalpha << range.empty() << "\n";

    range = boost::make_iterator_range(is.end(), is.end());
    std::cout << "range empty? " << std::boolalpha << range.empty() << "\n";

    is.clear();

    range = {};
    std::cout << "range empty? " << std::boolalpha << range.empty() << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
range empty? false
range empty? true
range empty? true
```

Comment: Am I right in my understanding that in the above example,  is.begin() and is.end() return rvalues? I think so because lvalues can be returned from a function only if the function is returning by reference. And in this case, both is.begin() and is.end() return by value.

Comment: @SharuGupta on matters as these, refer to [the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html) which confirms that. It is ubiquitous design convention to pass/return iterators by value (as they enrich the pointer concept). Lastly, `iterator_range<>` models a `Range` concept, not a `pair<>` or `tuple<>` of iterators. If it were, it would make mildly more sense to expect the iterators to be exposed by reference